# How to pass Array of Objects in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

```js
export default {
  name: 'SearchAutocomplete',
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
      default: () => [],
    },
    isAsync: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false,
      results: [],
      search: '',
      isLoading: false,
      arrowCounter: -1,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    items: function (value, oldValue) {
      if (value.length !== oldValue.length) {
        this.results = value;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside)
  },
  destroyed() {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside)
  },
  methods: {
    setResult(result) {
      this.search = result;
      this.isOpen = false;
    },
    filterResults() {
      this.results = this.items.filter((item) => {
        return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
    },
    onChange() {
      this.$emit('input', this.search);

      if (this.isAsync) {
        this.isLoading = true;
      } else {
        this.filterResults();
        this.isOpen = true;
      }
    },
    handleClickOutside(event) {
      if (!this.$el.contains(event.target)) {
        this.isOpen = false;
        this.arrowCounter = -1;
      }
    },
    onArrowDown() {
      if (this.arrowCounter < this.results.length) {
        this.arrowCounter = this.arrowCounter + 1;
      }
    },
    onArrowUp() {
      if (this.arrowCounter > 0) {
        this.arrowCounter = this.arrowCounter - 1;
      }
    },
    onEnter() {
      this.search = this.results[this.arrowCounter];
      this.isOpen = false;
      this.arrowCounter = -1;
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="autocomplete">
    <input
      type="text"
      @input="onChange"
      v-model="search"
      @keydown.down="onArrowDown"
      @keydown.up="onArrowUp"
      @keydown.enter="onEnter"
    />
    <ul
      id="autocomplete-results"
      v-show="isOpen"
      class="autocomplete-results"
    >
      <li
        class="loading"
        v-if="isLoading"
      >
        Loading results...
      </li>
      <li
        v-else
        v-for="(result, i) in results"
        :key="i"
        @click="setResult(result)"
        class="autocomplete-result"
        :class="{ 'is-active': i === arrowCounter }"
      >
        {{ result }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

How to Pass Array of Objects

```js
  :items="[
        'Apple',
        'Banana',
        'Orange',
        'Mango',
        'Pear',
        'Peach',
        'Grape',
        'Tangerine',
        'Pineapple'
      ]"
```

I am working on vue auto complete search,  and i am having some values which i need to pass inside search, But issue is on how to pass array of objects to the  search, Below i am attaching :items values which need to be pass the values to search.

Can you please help me on this.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question now.

Comment: Basically i am working on autocomplete search, and Struck at  passing array of object to search

Comment: Why are you trying to pass an array literal as a string in the attribute?

Comment: Basically i am new to vuejs, Tried creating auto complete, Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Taken reference from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-vue-autocomplete-component

Comment: Use a select input dropdown. Map the array of objects as autocomplete results. @keydown of the select input write down a function to sort/ filter the required results array, return and set that to the state.

Comment: Can you please provide an example

Comment: Taken reference from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-vue-autocomplete-component. there they are passing values in, But confused how to pass in js file

Comment: What is the problem here? Your code works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-franklin-gs6jh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thanks it's working, But instead of storing values in App.vue, Can we able to pass the values in Scripting file

Comment: Sure. You can define reactive stuff inside data in parent component and pass it into props of the component: https://codesandbox.io/s/new-thunder-e54q9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark